# How to perform ordering in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I have table in `Cassandra` which includes a field id. I have set that field as `partition key`. Now I want to query that table order by id.
How can I select all rows from that table in the order of id using `Cql`?

Comment: A few months ago I wrote an article that describes how to leverage sort order in Cassandra.  Give it a read and it may help you understand how to design a data model to support your requirements: http://planetcassandra.org/blog/we-shall-have-order/

Comment: thanks @BryceAtNetwork23. that was very informative .So in normal cases, like ,if we want to store a student data base, in which each row is identified by a particular id and we need to retrieve the entire data in a particular order of id , then we cannot use this .. right ?I got another doubt , how exactly the replication work in Cassandra ? is the replication occur for each partition or for each row ? Can you please  explain that also ..thanks .

Comment: Correct; you cannot enforce a result set order on a `SELECT`, without a `WHERE` clause (specifying a partition key) in Cassandra.  And replication occurs at the partition.  That way all rows for a partition are guaranteed to be read from the same node.

Comment: Is there any alternatives for 'OR' and 'IN' in `cql` ?

Answer (score 2):

In Cassandra you cannot order by **partition key**.
You can only order within a **partition key**

Error from cql:

```
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Order by is currently only supported on the clustered 
columns of the PRIMARY KEY, got id"
```

You will have to create a table with **id** as **clustering key** and then order by **id**.